# Getting Uncaught Error: Invalid argument: null. in Dart

Tags: canvas, dart, html5-canvas, dart-html, dart-webui

I'm trying to draw a bouncing ball on a canvas created using dart and html bu I keep getting the error `Uncaught Error: Invalid argument: null`. What do I need to change?

I'm pretty new to dart and I'm using this example to learn

The code is at https://dartpad.dartlang.org/44f020233c9636f43087d235f96b1b4e

I want to make the ball on the canvas to bounce on the canvas being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is really misleading here (you should [file a bug](http://dartbug.com/new)) but the issue is because `canvas` variable is `null`. In the HTML file the canvas has id `surface` so you should use:

```
canvas = querySelector('#surface');
```

Comment: Thanks... I've made the changes and changed the gist to https://dartpad.dartlang.org/44f020233c9636f43087d235f96b1b4e. Now I'm getting a new error `Uncaught Error: Invalid argument: null`

Comment: There's an issue in the Ball constructor declaration. Use `Ball(this.radius);` instead of `Ball(double radius) { radius; } `.

Comment: Sorry I know this is annoying but the mousedown eventlistener is not working..Could you please help me out?

Comment: 2 issues : use `canvas.onMouseDown.listen(doMouseDown);` instead of `canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown);` and use `event.page.x` instead of `event.pageX`

Comment: What changes do I have to make to make the ball move on mouse click ??